# Flask 400 Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand JSON

Tags: python, json, curl, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to send the following JSON object via curl to my Flask application I get error 400. I think this is because of the value in script that has many special characters, when I replace the value there with 'test', it works fine, I am using Windows.

**the curl request**

```
curl -X POST -d @example_post.json http://test/hlt  --header "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

**the data:**

```
{
    "item-type": "Magazine",
    "clip-id": "",
    "source-language": null,
    "target-language": "de",
    "item-id": "0000000b000ca0d5",
    "item-title": "Drone Malaui | SHIS200207_001_MalawiDrones_01F",
    "publication-title": "",
    "video-path": "test_files/TestFile.mp4",
    "ftp-url": "test_files/TestFile.mp4",
    "script": " ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Bilder:  The_power_of_hope1.KONF.20728229++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Première:  SHIS200207_001_MalawiDrones_01F++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Titel:evo aquí he hecho este drone. Lo construí con mis propias manos, con los materiales que nos proporcionan en el curso. Nos dieron los materiales y nos explicaron cómo emplearlos. Seguí las instrucciones y aquí está el resultado.\\\"+++1:34Ellos son los 26 primeros alumnos de los 150 que la academia planea formar antes de finales de 2021. A partir de 2022, está previsto ofrecer una maestría en tecnología de drones. 1:49  +++SOT Rudolf Schwenk, UNICEF Malawi country representative+++\\\"Es un paso importante para ayudar a los jóvenes a adquirir habilidades del siglo XXI. La década que recién comenzó va a ser digital, y ayudar a los jóvenes a mejorar sus habilidades y aprender tecnología digital y manejo de drones va a suponer un avance enorme, no sólo para Malawi, sino también para muchos otros países de África.\\\"+++2:13Gracias a jóvenes como ellos, la tecnología de los drones con fines humanitarios podrá levantar vuelo y servir de ejemplo a otros países. "
}
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/mydomain', methods=['POST'])

    def upload_videos():
        print('request=', request.json, file=sys.stderr)
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = request.get_json()
            if data is not None:
               # print('request=', request, file=sys.stderr)
                res = upload_file(data, bucket)
                print(res, file=sys.stderr)
                return(res)
        return 'no data found'
```

Comment: What is the type of `res` in your case? May you try to wrap it into jsonify?

Comment: I tried to run your code inside Docker container and it works fine. Remark: I don't have access to the `upload_file` function, so I am returning input json.

Comment: The error generates from using json values that have non English characters inside. and only happens on windows system, however when I save my file as utf-8 it goes through

Comment: however when I only add --header "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8" into my curl request but dont save the file as utf-8 it does not go through

Comment: check this out https://blog.furas.pl/python-unicode-decode-encode.html I think its better if you use latin2 or windows-1250.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the charset to "latin-1" (ISO-8859-1)? This is often the problem when working with windows data. Latin 1 represents the first 256 code points of the Unicode character set. Code points 0 - 127 get encoded as if UTF-8 is being used, but code points 128 - 255 are encoded as single bytes with Latin-1 and 2-byte sequences with UTF-8. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 for more information.